# How to structure ASP .Net Core 6 Application including Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, clean-architecture, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm new to ASP .Net core and I'm trying to structure my solution following the clean architecture pattern including Identity - Individual User Accounts.

So far here is how it looks the structure of my solution:

```
MyProject.sln
 -MyProject.UI.Web
 -MyProject.Shared.Models //DTOs
 -MyProject.Persistence //Manages data access and storage.
 -MyProject.Infrastructure //Implements use cases and application logic.
 -MyProject.Domain 
 -MyProject.Application //Implements use cases and application logic.
 -MyProject.Api //Builds API endpoints.
```

Adding Identity - Individual User Accounts in my `MyProject.UI.Web`
project, by default it adds the foldes:

```
- Areas
- Data
  - Migrations
  - ApplicationDbContext
```

What I want is to move the `Data` folder to `MyProject.Persistence` because that's where I have the migrations, repositories, my `DbContext` class.

The scenario:

1. Loading up the Login page
2. User inserts data to log in
3. In the MyProject.UI.Web, controller validates the model and calls the service
4. The service calls the API
5. API return OK / KO

I want to go through the API because I want to have same mechanism for Desktop APP and Mobile APP.

---

**What I tried:**

Moving `Data` folder to `MyProject.Infrastructure` and installing :

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

but then I have problem with the [configuration of the default identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5zsd.png) in `Program.cs` because I don't have `EntityFrameworkCore` anymore in my `MyProject.UI.Web project`

**Question:**
If all this makes sence can someone explain me step by step how to move the `Data` folder to `MyProject.Persistence` and I prefer to not have `EntityFrameworkCore` in my `MyProject.UI.Web` project.

Comment: If you want to put the identity EFCore to another project, you should implement the Userstore and rolestore by yourself(custom storage provider). Then inside the this two store, you could use Persistence's service to manage the database. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-7.0). About the example about how to implement, you could check the examples like dapper page or else like [this](https://github.com/grandchamp/Identity.Dapper/tree/master/src/Identity.Dapper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce an extension class and method in `MyProject.Persistence` which calls `ConfigureIdentityContext<>`. In this case your `MyProject.UI.Web` has to reference `MyProject.Persistence` project and not `EntityFrameworkCore` directly. So, here how it can all work:

1. Create the extension class in `MyProject.Persistence`:

```
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    …
    public static void ConfigureMyIdentityContext(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.ConfigureIdentityContext<DbContext>();
    }
}
```

2. Make sure `MyProject.UI.Web` has a reference to `MyProject.Persistence`
3. In `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    …
    services.ConfigureMyIdentityContext();
    services.AddIdentity();
}
```

You can check the details here:
https://github.com/devInstance/DevCoreApp/blob/d9edc7246f40597d35c18785401d789791784858/src/Server/Database/SqlServer/ConfigurationExtensions.cs#L26

...and here:

https://github.com/devInstance/DevCoreApp/blob/d9edc7246f40597d35c18785401d789791784858/src/Server/WebService/Startup.cs#L65